# Does Web Push in mobile Safari work starting from iOS 17.4 update in Europe?

Tags: ios, mobile, push-notification, safari, progressive-web-apps

According to Apple's announcement regarding app distribution in the EU **starting from iOS 17.4, they will be discontinuing support for Home Screen web apps in the EU**.

The excerpt from the article states: "EU users will still be able to access websites directly from their Home Screen through a bookmark, with minimal impact on functionality."

From what I've gathered online, the limitations will include:

- Sending notifications and displaying badges
- Offline support
- Seamless integration

I would like to know **if Web Push in Safari for iOS in the EU will cease to function as it did prior to iOS 16.4, or if it will be just limited in some way**.

I would appreciate any real test results.

Comment: I have same question. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not working in IOS 17.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).